# Loop through an array in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to output the arrays in array `pakket`. This is the output of the array when I am printing it on the page:

```
Array
(
    [bestellen-form] => 969a836d85
    [_wp_http_referer] => /bestellen-2/
    [looptijd] => Array
        (
            [looptijd_keuze] => 1 maand
            [looptijd_prijs] => 148.00
        )

    [naam] => Jari Rengeling
    [email] => jarirengeling@outlook.com
    [phone] => 0629153674
    [pakket] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pakket_type] => Zilver
                    [pakket_prijs] => 59
                    [pakket_veilig_thuiswerken] => 5.00
                    [domein_incl_hosting] => 00.00
                    [uur_service] => 10.00
                    [onbeperkt_data] => 00.00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [pakket_type] => Brons
                    [pakket_prijs] => 29
                    [domein_incl_hosting] => 00.00
                    [uur_service] => 10.00
                    [onbeperkt_data] => 00.00
                )

        )

)
```

This is the output I want:

```
Pakket 1:
Zilver

Pakket 2:
Brons
```

I am trying it with following code but I am getting following warning:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'pakket'
```

The for loop I am using:

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    foreach ($element['pakket'] as $pakket) {
        echo $pakket['pakket_type'];
    }
}
```

Does someone know why it is not working?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've tried - the $element **is** the "pakket" array. So `$element['pakket']` means there's an element named "pakket" in the array "pakket" (which doesn't exist).

You can use a condition to check if the "current" element is the "pakket" array.

```
foreach ($array as $element => $value) {
    if($element == "pakket") {
      foreach ($value as $pakket) {
          echo $pakket['pakket_type'];
      }
    }
}
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic isn't quite right, For your first loop each value of `$element` will be each item in the array one at a time, for example the first loop `$element` will equal `969a836d85`

Assuming there will always only be one 'pakket' key in the root of the array (and it will always be there) you can use

```
foreach ($array['pakket'] as $pakket) {
    echo $pakket['pakket_type'];
}
```